# How to get custom icon using leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, icons, marker

Now, I am loading in tweets from a database and plotting them on a map. I can't work out how to put in a Twitter icon instead of the normal blue markers from leaflet?

I've tried several solutions from the internet but none of them seem to work for me. I am new to this and still figuring out how a lot of it works.

Heres my JS code for fetching the data and plotting it:

```
var map;

function fetchData()    {
    
    //Create the map object and set the centre point and zoom level 
    map = L.map('map').setView([40.790011, -74.037404], 10);
        
    //Load tiles from open street map  
    L.tileLayer('http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution:'Map data ©OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA, Imagery ©CloudMade',
        maxZoom: 18
    //add the basetiles to the map object   
    }).addTo(map);
    
    //Define array to hold results returned from server
    tweetData = new Array();
    
    //AJAX request to server; accepts a URL to which the request is sent 
    //and a callback function to execute if the request is successful. 
    $.getJSON("fetchData.php", function(results)    { 
        
        //Populate tweetData with results
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++ )   {
            
            tweetData.push ({
                id: results[i].id, 
                body: results[i].body, 
                lat: results[i].lat, 
                lon: results[i].lon
            }); 
        }
        
        plotTweets(); 
    })
};

function plotTweets() {
    
    
   //Loop through tweetData to create marker at each location
   for (var i = 0; i < tweetData.length; i++) {
      var markerLocation =
         new L.LatLng(tweetData[i].lat, tweetData[i].lon);
      var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation);
      map.addLayer(marker);
      marker.bindPopup(tweetData[i].body);
   }
   
}


function clearData()    {
    document.getElementById('textWrap').innerHTML = ''; 
}
```

I have the icon ready called twitter_icon.png

In my HTML I have the link to the leaflet styles sheet

```
<!--This is a link to the Leaflet stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, would be great.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've added this piece of code from the leaflet website, but now instead of default blue markers, there are no markers!

```
function plotTweets() {
    
    var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'twitter_icon.png',
    iconSize: [16, 16],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowUrl: 'twitter_icon.png',
    shadowSize: [16, 16],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});

   //Loop through tweetData to create marker at each location
   for (var i = 0; i < tweetData.length; i++) {
      var markerLocation =
         new L.LatLng(tweetData[i].lat, tweetData[i].lon);
      L.marker([markerLocation], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
      marker.bindPopup(tweetData[i].body);
   }
   
}
```

Error code I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null leaflet.js:5 
    at Object.project (leaflet.js:5)
    at Object.latLngToPoint (leaflet.js:5)
    at e.project (leaflet.js:5)
    at e.latLngToLayerPoint (leaflet.js:5)
    at e.update (leaflet.js:7)
    at e.onAdd (leaflet.js:7)
    at e._layerAdd (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.whenReady (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.addTo (leaflet.js:6)
```

But I have no idea what this means!

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Comment: @IvanSanchez I've already looked through this, I can't work out where to put that code/edit the var marker code I already have?

Comment: Your new code very probably generates some errors in your browser devtools console. You should also have a look at the devtools network tab to check that the requested path to your custom icon matches your file structure. Please add thpse details to your question if you still need help.

Comment: I've posted the error message now, though I don't know what it means. Yes, the image file is in the right directory to work with everything else I have. Thanks

Comment: I've figured it out. Have posted working code as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out how to make it work.

Here's the end working code:

```
var map;
var tweetData;
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'twitter_icon2.png',
    iconSize: [25, 25],
    iconAnchor: [0, 0],
    popupAnchor: [0, 0],
    shadowUrl: 'twitter_shadow.png',
    shadowSize: [22, 22],
    shadowAnchor: [1, 1]
});

function fetchData()    {
    
    //Create the map object and set the centre point and zoom level 
    map = L.map('map').setView([40.790011, -74.037404], 10);
        
    //Load tiles from open street map  
    L.tileLayer('http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution:'Map data ©OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA, Imagery ©CloudMade',
        maxZoom: 18
    //add the basetiles to the map object   
    }).addTo(map);
    
    //Define array to hold results returned from server
    tweetData = new Array();
    
    //AJAX request to server; accepts a URL to which the request is sent 
    //and a callback function to execute if the request is successful. 
    $.getJSON("fetchData.php", function(results)    { 
        
        //Populate tweetData with results
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++ )   {
            
            tweetData.push ({
                id: results[i].id, 
                body: results[i].body, 
                lat: results[i].lat, 
                lon: results[i].lon
            }); 
        }
        
        plotTweets(); 
    })
};

function plotTweets() {

   //Loop through tweetData to create marker at each location
   for (var i = 0; i < tweetData.length; i++) {
      var markerLocation =
         new L.LatLng(tweetData[i].lat, tweetData[i].lon);
   var marker = L.marker(markerLocation, {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
      marker.bindPopup(tweetData[i].body);
   }
   
}


function clearData()    {
    document.getElementById('textWrap').innerHTML = ''; 
}
```